# How does the module pattern know how to call the constructor here?

Tags: javascript

What is the connection between the outer var Message and the inner var Message?

**The Call**

```
new Message ( element ).display( server_response_text.slice( 6 ) );
```

**Object**

```
var Message = ( function () 
{
    var messages = 
    {
        name:         'Please enter a valid name',
        email:        'Please enter a valid email',
        email_s:      'Please enter a valid email.',
        pass:         'Please enter passoword, 6-40 characters',
        url:          'Please enter a valid url',
        title:        'Please enter a valid title',
        tweet:        'Please enter a valid tweet',
        empty:        'Please complete all fields',
        same:         'Please make emails equal',
        taken:        'Sorry, that email is taken',
        validate:     'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:here@host.com">support</a> to reset your password',
    };
    var Message = function (element) 
    {
        this.element = element;
    };
    Message.prototype.display = function( type ) 
    {
        this.element.innerHTML = messages[ type ];
        new Effects().fade( this.element, 'down', 4000 );
    };
    return Message;
} () );
```

My entire library is using the module pattern like this

```
    var NS = ( function ( window, undefined ) 
    {
    /*
    all code here including Message
    */
    } )( window );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relationship<sup>1</sup> to the variable names at all.

It is just the name used inside. It might as well be `fuubar`:

```
var fuubar = function (element) 
{
    this.element = element;
};
fuubar.prototype.display = function( type ) 
{
    this.element.innerHTML = messages[ type ];
    new Effects().fade( this.element, 'down', 4000 );
};
return fuubar; // the Object is returned, the Variable (Name) is not
```

It makes sense that the *outer* name is `Message`, because that is how it is "known" to others. <sup>1</sup>The inner name was likely chosen for consistency, but otherwise does not affect semantics.

Constructors are just function-objects [designed to be] invoked with the *new* operator. Variables can name objects. In this case note that it is the *function-object* that is returned. Thus the *function-object* is known by the name `Message` (e.g. "is assigned to Message") outside. However, a *variable is not an object*.

Thus `new X()` evaluates the expression `X`, which must evaluate to a function-object, and then uses it as a constructor. (A constructor is just a normal function that expects to be used with `new`: it may perform initialization and establish a [[prototype]]). The name `X` is *not important* except insofar as it must evaluate to a function-object. Consider this equivalent form to show: `new (X)()`. The expression `(X)` is evaluated *first*.

So, let's break down the code:

```
var Message = (function () {
   // This function is invoked immediately, due to the
   // parenthesis immediately after the FunctionExpression.
   // As noted above the name Message used inside is not important.
   // What *IS* important is that a Constructor, which is just
   // a function-object (which is just an object) is returned.
   // This returned object will be assigned to (the outer)
   // Message variable. That is, it is "named by Message"
   // after the assignment occurs.
})()

// At this point Message will evaluate to a function-object
// (a Constructor in particular).
Message instanceof Function // -> true

// And we can use it to create new messages:
var messageA = new Message("a")
var messageB = new Message("b")
```

Happy coding.

Comment: How does the interpreter know where to pass element to the constructor, particularly if it was called fubar?

Comment: wait a minute..how can i return something that was never instantiated to begin with?

Comment: @TheAllFoo You are returning a function-object that was created with `function () {...}`.

Comment: Yes, it has been assigned a value: `var Message = STUFFHERE; ...; return Message` <-- the value STUFFHERE is returned. The name has no bearing, as shown in my code. `var fuubar = STUFFHERE; ...; return foobar;` <-- the value STUFFHERE is returned.

Comment: Of course not. The return returns a *function-object* (STUFFHERE, e.g. result of `function () {}`) which is then assigned to *the outer* `Message`. This function-object, is an object, and new objects are created from it later with `new Message`.

Comment: it would make more sense if the return was 'return new Message()'

Comment: No it would not. That would return a 1 new object of said type. Instead you **return a constructor (which is a function-object)** so that you can make N new objects of said type when you **invoke the constructor with `new` later**. It is the difference between returning "a thing" and returning something that "knows how to make things". **Functions are objects too.**

Comment: ....so Message returns a constructor function which is than instantiated using new from the original call....

Comment: Outer "Message" is just a var that gets set to a value -- it's not a function.  It is set by the anonymous, immediate function "( function ()..." that is called to set (outer) "Message".  I've commented the code you posted in my answer which maybe will make more sense to you.

Comment: I am returning a thing that knows how to make things than.

Comment: The immediate function returns a function (if you're originally from C++, think "function pointer") that is set into outer Message.  The code would have been clearer if the inner Message had been set to another name.

Comment: so new is actually working on the (return type of Message) and not ( Message)...please say yes and I got it.

Comment: `new` works on a *function-object*. A *function-object* was returned and thus assigned to (outer) `Message`. So "Sorta". There is only a constructor (which is a function). (For all objects created via `new Y` it will hold `y instanceof Y`, as long as Y *evaluates* to the same function. However, Y just *evaluates* to a function!)

Answer (score 3):

These variable references are equal, despite of the same name.

Inside the anonymous function, `Message` is a locally declared constructor.
A reference to this constructor is returned at the end of the function.

Test for identity:

```
window.Message = ( function () {
    ...
    // Defer call
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('Identity? ' + Message === window.Message);
    }, 100);
    return Message;
} () );
```

### Picture:

- The **green** `Message` object (constructor) is defined within the **red** block (function).
- At the end of this function, the created green `Message` object is returned.
- Right after the creation of the function, it is invoked using **`()`**. The return value (the **green box**) is passed to the **orange** `Message` variable.
- Now, the **orange** `Message` variable points to the **green** `Message` object/constructor. To clarify: **The green and orange `Message` variables refer to the same object**.
- An instance of this constructor is created using the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

[image]

Comment: If it is locally declared, how does it know when to run? and how does it "connect" to the call which passes element in?

Comment: @TheAllFoo A reference to the local `Message` is returned at the end of the function. This function is immediately invoked, so `var Message = ( /*function here*/ () )` points to this return value.

Comment: wait a minute..how can i return something that was never instantiated to begin with?...this should refer to nothing...because we return Message and it was never "ran" or "instantiated" it just points to a function.

Comment: @TheAllFoo In javaScript, `function(){return x;}` is no more than `Give x to the caller of the function`. Have a look at **[MDN: Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)**.

Comment: there is no new for the inner constructor, why does nobody else see this...yet it uses 'this' as if it was called with new.

Comment: @TheAllFoo From the top of your question: [**`new`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) `Message ( element ).display( server_response_text.slice( 6 ) );` - That creates the instance of the constructor.

Comment: so new is actually working on the (return type of Message) and not ( Message)...please say yes and I got it.

Comment: @TheAllFoo I've added a picture to my answer.

Comment: I have found nothing more difficult in technology or in life, than learning Object Oriented javaScript..thanks again..that is an awesome drawing...they need to give out special badges for that.

Answer (score 1):

The outer Message gets set to the result of an immediate function call (the "( function ()...").  The return value of the immediate function is the inner Message, which is also set to a function (just after "var messages" close scope, the "var Message = function(element)" function.).

When you call new Message outside of this code, it will call into the "var Message = function(element)" function to construct the object.

The reason to use this form is so that "messages" is kept in a closure -- essentially, it's private data.  Here's a commented version:

```
var Message = ( function ()     // Immediate function call
{
    // This is going to be private data - it's in a closure via the immediate function call
    var messages = 
    {
        name:         'Please enter a valid name',
        email:        'Please enter a valid email',
        email_s:      'Please enter a valid email.',
        pass:         'Please enter passoword, 6-40 characters',
        url:          'Please enter a valid url',
        title:        'Please enter a valid title',
        tweet:        'Please enter a valid tweet',
        empty:        'Please complete all fields',
        same:         'Please make emails equal',
        taken:        'Sorry, that email is taken',
        validate:     'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:here@host.com">support</a> to reset your password',
    };

    // This will be returned as the actual value of outer Message
    var Message = function (element) 
    {
        this.element = element;
    };

    // This adds to the prototype so it will be found in all instances of Message objects
    Message.prototype.display = function( type ) 
    {
        this.element.innerHTML = messages[ type ];
        new Effects().fade( this.element, 'down', 4000 );
    };

    // This is the return value of the immediate function call and becomes outer Message
    return Message;
} () );
```